# How to use printer friendly function with CTRL+p?

Tags: css, xslt, printing

The website I'm working on currently has a print-icon which pop ups  a printer-friendly page and the prints look fine. However, if the user hits CTRL+p (not pressing the "print icon") the printer friendly version is not used. So the problem is how do I get the user to print the printer-friendly version when they hit CTRL+p?

What might pose as an obstacle, is that the printer friendly page is generated using XSLT. Any ideas?

I've looked through some articles that involve using CSS, but then it seemed that I need to redefine/create new printer-friendly page/CSS-layout and I did not see how I could implement this with XSLT. I still include a CSS-tag, in case some of you brilliant minds have a way to solve this using CS. If it's not possible, I'm sorry for posting with wrong tags..

Comment: I'd like to add that the printer-friendly page that pop ups needs an id-number to know which article to print.

Comment: Have you thought of using @media print {} in your css to provide different layout for your printer friendly page?  That way you generate a single page and just lay it out differently using css?

Comment: I thought of that in the sense that I've seen some examples of it and I didn't see how I could use that approach in this case. All data is given through XML, which in turn is processed by XSLT to display the page in a printer-friendly manner. I fail to see how I can mix these two..?

Comment: Because you use the XSLT to render the HTML for the page, but then you use the CSS to override its layout.  What is the difference between your printer friendly and on screen layout?

Comment: The site use a traditional style where you got a column on each side of the article, as well as one right above. The date which is under the preface is moved to right above the title. Above this again, the logo of the website is displayed. My CSS on this topic is rather lacking, so detailed feedback is appreciated! :)

Comment: The best bet would be to set the non printable elements with a css class of `noprint` and then in your style sheet put `@media print { .noprint { display:none; }}`

Comment: I can't say I got an overview over it yet, but it seems like a good idea! :) You don't happen to know of a site with a good example or tutorial on the matter?

Comment: Could you update your question with a link to a sample page for screen and a sample for print output?

Comment: @Bob Vale , question updated. Tips? :) If not, just post what you've said in these comments as an answer and I'll approve it. Thanks!

Comment: @pecka85 "a good example or tutorial" It's not really hard to find print-style examples on the WWW, but hey I've google for you lazy:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: @feeela I did visit that website. As I mentioned in my question, I did research before posting my question. However, it didn't seem to solve my problem the easy way I would like. Maybe you should start reading the whole question before coming with remarks you don't know anything about and/or have no grounds to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a style sheet with the @media print option to hide the none print elements.

I've had a quick go and I think I've stripped most elements, you should be able to tweak this further to better suit your needs.

```
@media print {

  #col1,#col2 { display:none; }

  #crumbs,#header_smallmenu,#header_search { display:none;}

  .solidblockmenu { display:none; }

  .addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style { display:none;}

  #hbfooter, .hbfooter { display:none; }

  body {background-image: none;}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this a job for Javascript?

If you capture the onKeyDown event, you could catch when CTRL+P is pressed, and fire off your own javascript to open up your printer friendly page

```
function overrideKeyDown(winEvent)
{
    var keyCode; 

    if(!winEvent) 
    { 
              // IE code
        winEvent = window.event; 
        keyCode = winEvent.keyCode; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        keyCode = winEvent.which; 
    } 

    if (keyCode == 80 && winEvent.ctrlKey)
    {
        alert('Printer Friendly Page');
        return false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = overrideKeyDown;
```

This works in IE and Chrome, but annoyingly Firefox still pops up the Printer dialog as well as running the Javascript. However, I thought I would post the code anyway, just in case it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Tim C! Unfortunately, I need support for Firefox as well.

Comment: "Isn't this a job for Javascript?" No, it's a job for CSS! See @Bob Vale's answer.